# working with datagrid to show the data from database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working a dictionary project in winform.i have a textbox where i enter my text.whenever i enter any text i will show the words and its meaning where word=my_entered_text.
I tried like this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string word = textBox1.Text;

        //connect to database
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Documents\new2.sdf");


        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            // 2
            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
               "SELECT English FROM Table1 WHERE (English like '" + word + "%')", con))
            {
                // 3
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);
                // 4
                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView2.DataSource = t;
            }

            using (SqlCeDataAdapter b = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
                "SELECT Bangla FROM Table1 WHERE (English like '" + word + "%')", con))
            {
                // 3
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable tt = new DataTable();
                b.Fill(tt);
                // 4
                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;

            }
        }
    }
```

But it showing an exception that is "Parameter is not valid" at the line "  dataGridView1.DataSource = tt;"
How can i solve this???

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT Bangla FROM Table1 WHERE (English like '" + word + "%')"
```

PS. *'English' column may not be existing in the table Bangla*